# Ember.js: how do I override one of my superclass's actions in a component?

Tags: ember.js

This is Ember.js 2.11. If I have a Component:

app/components/a/component.js

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
   actions: {
      foo() { ... }
   }
});
```

and another component which inherits from it:

app/components/b/component.js

```
import A from 'components/a';

export default Ember.Component.extend(A, {
  ...
});
```

How do I override `foo` in `B`? Defining my own `actions` object does not appear to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `actions` hash is mergedProperties that's the reason for it's not overriding. You can see it [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.11.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/action_handler.js#L25).
You can see merged properties explanation [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#property_mergedProperties)

> Defines the properties that will be merged from the superclass (instead of overridden).

You can just extend like the below,

```
import A from 'components/a';

export default A.extend({
  ...
  actions: {
    foo() { ... }
  }
});
```

You can define `foo` actions in component-b. if you want to call foo action of component a from component-b you can call `this._super(...arguments)`.

[Sample twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/2dbe22ec692137627480770237cead75?openFiles=components.a-2.js%2Ctemplates.components.a-2.hbs)

Comment: Ah, thanks. Turns out my problem was something different (something not in my minimal example).